# Inheritance and functions with different return types

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

I have the following classes set up like this:

```
class Test
{
    public virtual subSmallObject CreateSmallObject
   {
       return new subSmallObject();
   }
}

abstract class subSmallObject
{  string test;  }
class subSmallObjectA : subSmallObject
{  string testA;  }
class subSmallObjectB : subSmallObject
{  string testB;  }
```

Now, instead of using Test class everywhere, I need to use a derived class of Test, let's call them class TestA and TestB. Test A and B need to have the CreateSmallObject class return either subSmallObjectA or SubSmallObjectB.

So typically I could just do

```
class TestA : Test
{
    override subSmallObject CreateSmallObject()
    {
        return new subSmallObjectA();
    }
}
class TestB : Test
{
    override subSmallObject CreateSmallObject()
    {
        return new subSmallObjectB();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I can't then cast the subSmallObject return from those to subSmallObjectA or subSmallObjectB, due tot he requirements of the task at hand (it would break a lot of things that I don't have control over. Those things expect either smallSubObjectA or subSmallObjectB). There will be shared elements between subSmallObjectA and subSmallObjectB. I don't want to eliminate the virtual function because some code will be repeated if there are two separate methods.

Is there any pattern or any practice out there that I'm missing? I'm a bit lost on this and such architectural changes are beyond me, since I don't really know the "proper" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to cast the results of a method call is...strange.
If you absolutely can't, you could try a generic factory method:

```
class SubObject{
    public string Data;
}
class SubObjectA{
}
class SubObjectB{
}
class Test{
    T GetSubObject<T>() where T:SubObject,new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Used Like

```
SubObjectA so=testInstance.GetSubObject<SubObjectA>();
```

That way you don't have to have the cast at the call site. It's not gonna work if SubObject doesn't have a default constructor though.